# Why is overloaded method selected with direct superclass parameter rather than Object?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, static, overload-resolution

```
public class Main {
    static void method(A a){
        System.out.print("one");
    }

    static void method(B b){
        System.out.print("two");
    }

    static void method(Object obj){
        System.out.print("three");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C(); 

        method(c);
    }
}
class A {}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
```

As you see the title, i think it displays "three" but true answer is "two". Anyone can explain me? Thankss!

Comment: Why not run and [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it for yourself?

Comment: Overloading will resolve to the most specific type that applies to the argument. The most specific type that applies to a reference of type C is B.

Comment: I want to learn order of java. I can't find related tutorial, all of tutorials show 2+2 = 4 like that.

Comment: @khelwood So, it goes to closest class to reference, bottom to top. Isn't it ?

Comment: @EmreKÖK That depends what you mean by "bottom" and "top" in this context. If you mean the furthest down the inheritance hierarchy, with superclass above subclasses, then yes.

Comment: don't know why it gets so downvoted... anyany you (and me) got  the answer from khelwood! just to mention, instead of printing one, two or three, why you don't print the type of the argument, i mean.. "A", "B" or "Object"..

Comment: @Victor It's my quiz question, i didn't think change it.

Comment: humble suggestion it was, you can't arguee is more straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading will resolve to the most specific type that applies to the argument. All of `A`, `B` and `Object` could apply to `C`, but the most specific of those is `B`. So `method(B)` will be called.

If `C` did not extend `A` or `B`, then `method(Object)` would be called.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what's the title of this topic? How can I find related examples and even more?

Comment: I would call it overload resolution.